# Excel VBA ADO UPDATE SQL Table/Record

Tags: vba, excel, sql-update, ado

I have managed to update an SQL table and record by using this SQL string

```
"UPDATE Breach_Test_Key SET [VAL_BREACH_REASON] = 'SOME BREACH REASON'  WHERE  [ID] = 1"
```

Two things I am trying to achieve and that is:

1. Update two specific columns in the SQL Table, how do I define two
   columns in the SET?
2. I also need to update all records that are in a table in Excel back
   into an SQL table (which will all exist in the SQL table).

The ID field will always match as the data is from this table.

Please could someone guide me through the SQL structure for this please?

Thank you @MatteoNNZ for help with part 1, this is the code I am now using to update multiple columns

```
uSQL = "UPDATE Breach_Test_Key SET [VAL_BREACH_REASON] = 'SOME BREACH REASON1',[VAL_BREACH_DETAIL] = 'SOME BREACH DETAIL1'  WHERE  [ID] = 1"
```

So for part two, I haven't actually got anything sufficient to post but where I have specified a value in the string I would rather it be dynamic to loop through the excel table/column. Any pointers?

Comment: Have a  look at the [syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp) as for the point 1. Try also to write your SQL statements before, so people will have something to fix instead of having to write all from scratch

Comment: Thanks @MatteoNNZ OK so I have managed to do part 1 which may or may not be the correct method but it works. This is how I have achieve it ' uSQL = "UPDATE Breach_Test_Key SET [VAL_BREACH_REASON] = 'SOME BREACH REASON' WHERE  [ID] = 1" & _
        "UPDATE Breach_Test_Key SET [VAL_BREACH_DETAIL] = 'SOME BREACH DETAIL'  WHERE  [ID] = 1" '

Comment: Part 2 is where I would like some sort of loop to loop through the excel table ID column to match back to SQL table and update that record. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Please add your result to the body of your question, so that someone who knows more about it can help you to optimize the code and help you with the point 2. I think you don't need to concatenate two UPDATE statements, you can use just one and separating column = value by comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I got the results I wanted.
The records are being updated as expected using a loop option in the vba.
It may not be the prettiest way of doing what I was trying to achieve but it works.

If anyone would like to suggest improvements then I am all ears.
But here is my final macro:

```
Private Sub UpdateTable()

Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim uSQL As String
Dim strWard As String
Dim strDate As Date
Dim strUser As String


'=====USER NAME VBA================
    Set WSHnet = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
    UserName = WSHnet.UserName
    UserDomain = WSHnet.UserDomain
    Set objUser = GetObject("WinNT://" & UserDomain & "/" & UserName & ",user")
    UserFullName = objUser.FullName
'===================================


'strDate is a stamp of the date and time when the update button was pressed
strDate = Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
'User is the username of the person logged into the PC the report is updated from
strUser = UserFullName


'Set Connection string
Set cnn = New Connection
cnnstr = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; " & _
            "Data Source=ServerName; " & _
            "Initial Catalog=dbName;" & _
           **USER DETAILS HERE**

'Connect and Run the SQL statement to update the reords.
cnn.Open cnnstr
Dim row As Range
For Each row In [tbl_data].Rows
    uSQL = "UPDATE Breach_Test_Key SET [VAL_BREACH_REASON] = '" & (row.Columns(row.ListObject.ListColumns("VAL_BREACH_REASON").Index).Value) & _
    "' ,[VAL_BREACH_DETAIL] = ' " & (row.Columns(row.ListObject.ListColumns("VAL_BREACH_DETAIL").Index).Value) & _ 
    "' WHERE  [ID] = '" & (row.Columns(row.ListObject.ListColumns("ID").Index).Value) & "'"

    'Debug.Print uSQL
cnn.Execute uSQL
Next

cnn.Close
Set cnn = Nothing
Exit Sub
End Sub
```